# Table column header width not the same as the table body and scrollbar too big

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working on a table that looks like this:

**There are 2 issues here:**

1. the column header `IPV6 Address` is taking small width than the body's column width. And Model and Type are not in place. How to fix this?
2. I want the scrollbar only when the table columns are not fitting the screen.

Comment: As far as I am aware btw you want the tag for `angular` not `angularjs`

Comment: Could you create [a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com)?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using white-space: nowrap. This might be the cause of your column width issues. Try removing this to see what it looks like multi-line, this will allow the table contents to at least attempt to use the available space properly without being forced over the space provided causing the effect with the "IPv6 Address" that you see.

Most of the time if I have fixed widths for columns (especially with nowrap) in any table I look to truncate the contents of the text within if I want everything to display on one line neatly and not wrap.

https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.2/api/directive/mdTruncate

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried removing it, but its still the same